# Another name for the trivial model structure

Tags: category-theory, terminology, model-categories

Any category $\mathcal C$ with finite limits and finite colimits can be seen as a model category where the weak equivalences are the isomorphisms, and the fibrations and cofibrations are all maps.

The nlab called it the [trivial model structure](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/trivial+model+structure) on $\mathcal C$. But *trivial* is already overloaded, especially in model categories (with trivial cofibrations, trivial fibrations). Another name that could fit is *discrete* as in such a category homotopy is equality: the spaces deduced from the hom-sets of the model category are discrete.  But again, *discrete* already denotes a set seen as a category; in particular *discrete model category* is ambiguous.

Is there any other established name for this model structure?

Comment: I've only ever seen it called the trivial model structure.  I'm not sure it matters so much since the model structure tells you nothing you didn't already know.

Comment: @Randall My situation is quite unusual : I have model categories that I want to consider sometimes with the trivial model structure for a bit before returning to their plain model structure. So I need a name to be precise about which model structure I'm considering.

Comment: Understood.  I just looked in my own papers (not that I should be trusted) and I've used the term trivial.  If I did that, it's probably because Hovey or Hirschhorn did, and they are actual trustworthy authorities.

Comment: @Randall Thanks. I guess I'll use _trivial_ then, and be careful to use _acyclic (co)fibrations_  to keep things clear. (Because of course, I also have Grothendieck fibrations, so I let you imagine the mess if I say "trivial fibration" without much context.)